# Sitecore, Commerce Cloud and Solr

Tags: solr, sitecore, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I'm working on a project where the content will be stored in Sitecore and the product catalog in Salesforce Commerce Cloud.
When the user searches for a keyword (say Toys), the search results must return the results
Toys in Articles (15 found) [Stored in Sitecore]
Toys in Products (25 found) [Stored in Commerce Cloud]

I was thinking of writing some kind of job that pulls this into Solr, that runs nightly. Is there a better way of doing this? Or is there a way to query the B2C commerce cloud index through C# dot net?

Answer (score 0):

This may come in too late, but in case someone else has similar question

Check the following REST APIs:

1. Commerce APIs
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/commerce-api/references/products?meta=searchProducts
2. OCAPI
   https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/current/shop/Resources/ProductSearch.html

Both of these provide REST API interface to product search in Salesforce Commerce Cloud.
If in doubt which one to use - use the Commerce API.